# Error when trying to get related table using Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$products = $em->getRepository('NameDemoBundle:Product')->findAllOrderedByName($id);
```

Function in repository:

```
public function findAllOrderedByName($name)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p,c FROM NameDemoBundle:Product p JOIN p.category c WHERE p.price = :name ORDER BY p.name ASC'
        )
        ->setParameter('name', $name)
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

And code works ok but I want to get to category related to results.

When I use `getSingleResult()` instead of `getResult()`, this code:

```
$category = $products->getCategory()->getName();
```

works fine, but on `getResults` when I have more than one result I have the error:

```
 Call to a member function getCategory() on a non-object
```

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: does this works for you or do you need more help ?

Comment: you should not post multiple answers, it's confusing. Try editing your answer instead .

Answer (score 0):

getResult returns a array of object, even if you have only one result, so you first have to parse $products to get each $product object like this

```
    foreach ( $products as $product )
    {

          $product->getcategory()->getName();
     }
```

hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

ok i have it

```
$category = array();
foreach ($products as $product)
{

            $category[] = $product->getcategory()->getName();
}
```

still now inside of theme i have to figure out

```
{% for product in product %}
            <li>{{ product.description }} | {{ product.id }} | {{category??}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: {{ product.category.name }} you can access to all related object of product simply like an array

Comment: ye i did that if some one need {{category[loop.index0]}} easy and quick thanks for help

Comment: so you should mark your question as answered by selecting the good answer, it's usefull for the community !